# twitter 2.0.2 not work with ruby 1.9.2dev

Tags: rubygems, twitter

I tried:

```
require "twitter"
LoadError: no such file to load -- twitter
```

My ruby version:

```
ruby --version
ruby 1.9.2dev (2010-07-02) [i486-linux]
```

My twitter version:

```
gem list
twitter (2.0.2)
```

File permission:

```
ls -all /var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/twitter-2.0.2/lib/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  567 2011-12-23 17:16 twitter.rb
```

I also tried to use Bundler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an outdated Ruby 1.9.2 development version. I strongly encourage you to upgrade to Ruby 1.9.2.

That said, before Ruby 1.9 RubyGems was not loaded by default. Depending on your development snapshot, you might or might not have these changes already included.

You can easily force the use of RubyGems using

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twitter'
```

Comment: Thanks, I upgrade my Ruby to 1.9.2 and get `require 'twitter' => true`! However, now when I start irb, I get an error `load error: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/.irbrc TypeError: can't convert nil into String`, everything still work fine, but I just wonder what the error message is about?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an issue on my system with Ruby 1.9.3-p0.  (Ubuntu 11.10, 64-bit.)  That's how I tried to reproduce:

```
fr@w500 ~ $ rvm -v

rvm 1.10.0-pre by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

fr@w500 ~ $ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
fr@w500 ~ $ gem -v
SlimGems 1.3.9.3
fr@w500 ~ $ gem install twitter
...
Successfully installed twitter-2.0.2
...
fr@w500 ~ $ irb
1.9.3-p0 :001 > require 'twitter'
 => true
```

If you don't have rvm or SlimGems, Google for those. I assume it should also work without them.

Comment: Thanks for rvm suggestion, now I can easily install and control Ruby version.